# Octave/MATLAB: Using a matrix to access elements in a matrix without loops

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, octave

Consider, the two matrices:

```
>> columns = [1,3,2,4]
```

and

```
>> WhichSet = 
       [2, 2, 1, 2;
        1, 1, 2, 1;
        1, 2, 1, 2;
        2, 1, 2, 2]
```

My intent is **to do the following**:

```
>> result = [WhichSet(1,columns(1)), WhichSet(2,columns(2)), WhichSet(3, columns(3)) and WhichSet(4, columns(4))]
result = [2,2,2,2]
```

**without any loops.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because how indexing works, you can not just plug them as they are now, unless you use **linear indexing**

Your desired linear indices are:

```
ind=sub2ind(size(WhichSet),1:size(whichSet,1),columns);
```

Then

```
out=WhichSet(ind);
```

Comment: I was trying out this method, but in my code I had columns as a column vector, so I was getting "all subscripts must be of same size" error. After looking at your solution, I realized that I just had to transpose it. Thank you so much! It works!